# Stopping a Location Listener

Tags: android

I Need to stop the location listener updates. I know that in order to stop a location listener I need to call `locationManager.removeUpdates(LocationListener)` but I keep getting an error of `MyLocationListener cannot be resolved to a variable`

Here is the code I have:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GetCoords extends Activity {

    private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; //in Meters
    private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 10000; //in Milliseconds

    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    protected Button getLocationButton;
    protected Button stopLocationButton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_coords);

        getLocationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.get_location_button);
        stopLocationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_location_button);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,
                MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                new MyLocationListener()
        );

        getLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showCurrentLocation();
            //String message = "GPS Service Started";
            Toast.makeText(GetCoords.this, "GPS Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    stopLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopMyLocation();
            //locationManager = null;
            //stopCurrentLocation();
            Toast.makeText(GetCoords.this, "GPS Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
        }

protected void stopMyLocation() {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(MyLocationListener);
            locationManager = null;
}
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong, every example I have seen of how to stop GPS updates makes me think that my code under stopMyLocation() is correct. I have tried it inside the stopLocationButton click listener, in its current location, pretty much everywhere and it keeps telling me that MyLocationListener is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save a reference to your LocationListener:

```
protected LocationManager locationManager;
protected MyLocationListener myLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();
```

Change this:

```
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,
            MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
            myLocationListener
    );
```

Now you can cancel it with:

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(myLocationListener);
```

Comment: now the myLocationListener in the locationManager.requestLocationUpdates( section highlights red, saying: "The method myLocationListener() is undefined for the type GetCoords". The name of the app is GetCoords just so you know where that piece is coming from. I'm beginning to think that Java is just beyond my capabilities, I mostly understand your corrections to my code, but cannot understand why it still will not work.

Comment: Remove the parathesis from `myLocationListener()` to make it simply `myLocationListener`. The paranthesis mean you are trying to call a method like `stopMyLocation()`, you want to access a variable which don't have parentheses.

Comment: Or, maybe if I had just followed your exact instructions instead of assuming I knew what I was doing I would have been fine. I had myLocationListener(), which is incorrect as per what you told me it needed to be myLocationListener, without the parenthesis. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I updated my comment with a little description of what parentheses mean in Java. The best teacher is failure, at least it is for me. :)

Comment: Thank you :) Honestly without this community I would not be attempting some of the projects I have recently taken on and would still be in my little PHP and Visual Basic shell pretending the rest of the world doesn't exist. I cannot thank you enough for taking the time out of your day to help me with what, honestly, was not the smartest question in the world.

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign your location listener to a field.. as in

```
protected MyLocationListener listener;
```

Then in your onCreate:

```
listener = new MyLocationListener();

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,
                MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                listener);
```

your unregister will then look like

```
 locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
```

Comment: Good answer! Less then three seconds apart... Have an upvote!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I marked @Sam as the correct answer just because it was first, but I did try your solution as well and it works equally as perfectly. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Glad it worked.I agree with marking Sam's correct since he answered first.

Answer (score 1):

You have initialized MyLocationListener, but not assigned it to a variable to be used later. How would Java know which instance of MyLocationListener class you're referring to in the `removeUpdates()` call?

1. Make a class variable `LocationListener abc;`
2. In the `onCreate()` method add the line abc = new MyLocationListener(); before you register for updates.
3. Pass this in your `requestLocationUpdates()` method.
4. call `removeUpdates(abc)` in your `stopMyLocation()` method.

Comment: Thank you for the help, even though it was already solved I appreciate your help as well, it does appear as if this would have worked equally as well but I think for now I am done beating on my code.

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because the stopMyLocation() function passes the unknown variable MyLocationListener to removeUpdates:

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(MyLocationListener);
```

To pass an existing variable to removeUpdates you have define an object variable of the MyLocationListener class which is accessible in the onCreate() and the stopMyLocation() function.

```
private MyLocationListener locationListener;
```

The locationListener variable can be instantiated in the onCreate() function and has to be used to call the requestLocationUpdates(...) function.

```
locationListener = new MyLocationListener();

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,
            MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
            locationListener
    );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I too was having the same issue. I think my problem was similar to the issues mentioned above as far as different instances of the listener being created. What I ended up doing was creating a static listener and creating a singleton method to prevent another instance of the listener from being created. The code looks something like this:

```
 static LocationListener mLocationListener = null;

 public LocationListener getLocationListener(){
    if(mLocationListener==null)
       mLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();
    return mLocationListener;
 }
```

Then I used it this way

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000 * 2, 0, getLocationListener());

locationManager.removeLocationUpdates(getLocationListener());
```

You could do the same thing with the locationmanager if necessary but I didnt have too. Hope this helps!